# UIAlertController auto layout warning

Tags: swift, autolayout, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have the code which works fine for all other buttons but it is not working for one specific button. The code is:

```
@IBAction func Quiz(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: "QuizLevel")

        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Please reset.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
```

The auto layout warning I get is:

```
2016-05-26 20:01:17.640 Quiz[4250:297386] <UIView: 0x7fca60571a80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fca6056d0c0>>'s window is not equal to <UIAlertController: 0x7fca60587620>'s view's window!
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Does your app use multiple windows?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by multiple windows?

Answer (score -3):

the present alert controller command would be in main thread because the change perform on the main screen that's why it shows you error.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey AppCoda", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   })
```

Comment: That code is being called from an `@IBAction`, it's already main thread and the error doesn't relate.

Comment: In swift 2.3 if we did't write the UIAlertController on main thread that it gives the  error in console constant generater error. so please keep your UIAlertController in main thread.

Comment: Read what I wrote.

Comment: sorry but there is a change you have assign some other operation like segue to that button . please check and let me know.